# Poles of $\sin(1/z)$

Tags: complex-analysis, trigonometry, singularity

i was studyng this function, and on wolfram alpha it says that there are no poles. But why is $z=0$ not a pole?

(sorry for my bad english)

Comment: Why is it not a pole in your opinion?

Comment: Did you try to plot $\sin(1/x)$ around $x=0$? Does it look like a pole? What is your definition of a pole?

Comment: how i can plot it ?

Comment: Lots of ways. Goto [Wolfram|Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sin(1%2Fx)) for one easy way.

Answer (score 4):

It is not a pole because it is an [essential singularity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Essential_singularity):$$\sin\left(\frac1z\right)=\frac1z-\frac1{3!z^3}+\frac1{5!z^5}-\frac1{7!z^7}+\cdots$$

Comment: how you figure it out ?

Comment: @Marià $$\sin(z)=z-\frac{z^3}{3!}+\frac{z^5}{5!}-\frac{z^7}{7!}+\cdots\implies\sin\left(\frac1z\right)=\frac1z-\frac1{3!z^3}+\frac1{5!z^5}-\frac1{7!z^7}+\cdots$$

Comment: our teacher just say to find the zero of the denominatori if the grade is the same of the numerator so it's a "deletable singularity" what kind of series do you write ?

Comment: is that taylor ?

Comment: @Marià Yes, that's the Taylor series of the $\sin$ function.

Comment: so if i have a function i can do the taylor series and from that how i can understand what kind of singularity is ?

Comment: @Marià If the Taylor series of $f$ is a polynomial, then $f\left(\frac1z\right)$ has a pole at $0$. Otherwise, it has an essential singularity there.

Comment: sorry i haven't understand. If the taylor series is polinomial it's a pole ?

Comment: @Marià Yes, that's what I wrote.

Comment: for instance the taylor series of the tangent is x+(x^3)/3+(x^5)2/15 so it's polinomial and which is the pole ? and why ? sorry i'm tryng to understand

Comment: @Marià No, it is not. The Taylor series of $\tan$ has infinitely many non-zero terms.

Comment: sorry i'havent undertand... the tan function isn't sen/cos so cos is at the denominator so pi/2 is a pole ?

Comment: @Marià Yes, $\frac\pi2$ is a pole of $\tan$. What has this to do with the question about the Taylor series of $\tan$ at $0$?

Comment: ehm... i 'm not understanding nothing... so if i have a function  tan(z) , sen(1/z) , cos(1/z) ,log(1/z)  or a mix of them or others... how i can identify poles ?

Comment: @Marià We are too far away from the original question. If you have another question, please post it as such.

Comment: ok :) thk you for the help.